# static int Xp = 0; static int PlayerLevel = 1+XP/300 ; can not reference a field before it is defined

Tags: java

so im making a text based game and i want it so that every(number)XP you level up or PlayerLevel+1

```
static int Xp = 0;  
static int PlayerLevel = 1+XP/300 ; 
can not reference a field before it is defined
```

Comment: You haven't really asked a question, and even your sole sentence doesn't make sense. Please read http://tinyurl.com/stack-hints

Comment: Is this a single player game? Why is it static?

Comment: yes it is single player

Comment: Then @ElliottFrisch is correct, you should not be using static fields for state variables. As an aside, you will want to learn and use [Java naming conventions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Naming_convention_(programming)#Java). Variable names should all begin with a lower letter while class names with an upper case letter. Also you should avoid using trivial variable names such as `xP` unless they are being used for trivial purposes such as the index of a for loop. Instead use names that have some meaning so that your code becomes self-commenting.

Comment: im sorry that i didn't quite directly ask a question but my question was answered so thank you. next time i ask i will use the guidelines

Comment: The answer given wouldn't result in the error message in the question. In other words, either your title is inappropriate, or you've got more code which you haven't shown us which is relevant to the question.

Answer (score 3):

Java is case sensitive. You define Xp and access XP.

BTW, if you meant to refer to the value of Xp, you could just init `PlayerLevel` to `1`, since (as you know) `1+0/300=1`.

Comment: Not sure why the down-vote on a correct answer. 1+